# Is the "define" primitive of Scheme an imperative languages feature? Why or why not?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, programming-languages

```
(define hypot
 (lambda (a b)
   (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))))
```

## This is a Scheme programming language.

- "define" creates a variable and global binding
- lambda creates a procedure

I would like to know if **"define"** would be considered as an imperative language feature! As long as I know imperative feature is static scoping. I think it is an imperative feature since **"define"** create a global binding and static scoped looks at global binding for any variable definition where as in dynamic it looks at the current most active binding.

Please help me find the correct answer!! And I would like to know why or why not?

Comment: Which definition of "imperative" are you using?

Comment: Here's the definition http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/imperative-language

Comment: So your question is "does define explicitly  manipulate state"?

Comment: Yes I want explanation towards that direction.

Answer (score 4):

In a Scheme program `(define var expr)` statement is both a declaration and an initialization. Declarations introduce a new name into the scope. Declarations and initialization are present in both imperative and declarative languages.

However if the same variable is defined twice, then `define` behave as an assignment - which belongs to the imperative paradigm.

Comment: Can you give me an example so I would know more about behaving as an assignment.

Comment: Upvoted but to nitpick: In Racket using `#lang racket` or `#lang r5rs`, `(define x 42) (define x 42)` gives a redefinition error in a module. [It's permitted in the REPL because the top-level is hopeless :).]  So actually I would say the spirit of `define` is like `let` -- not "imperative" in the question's sense.

Comment: `#lang racket` doesn't count (since it is not Scheme). The redefinition error in `#lang r5rs` I consider a bug. See http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.1

Comment: Well - I guess one could look at the bug as a feature :-)

Comment: Note that R7RS *explicitly indicates* that redefinition should behave *exactly* like `set!`, performing actual mutation, not just shadowing.

Comment: @AlexisKing  Internal definitions, that is any define not at the top level behaves like a letrec*, and trying to rebind a variable via define in the same procedure body is an error.

Answer (score 1):

You've put your finger on a subtle and contentious issue.  There have long been two informal camps on how `define` should work, which I would label (very imperfectly, and very controversially!) as the *static* vs. *dynamic* camps.

The static camp sees `define` as a non-side-effecting top-level declaration—it's a syntax that simply defines a name in a top-level scope, just like `let` is a syntax that defines a name in a local scope.  A bit more precisely, this camp tends to see the top-level environment as equivalent to a big `letrec` with all the `define`s as the bindings, and all "loose" top-level expressions as the body.  This is, incidentally, similar to the way that simple compilers work—read the whole program from one or more files, figure out all of the top-level bindings and generate code with knowledge of the whole program's source text.

The dynamic camp, on the other hand, tends to conceive of the top-level environment as a mutable data structure to which bindings can be added at runtime, and `define` is then an operation that modifies the top-level environment.  This is, incidentally, similar to how simple interactive interpreters work—read definitions interactively from input, one at a time, and incorporate them into the environment as the user provides them.

To give one example, the [SLIB library](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SLIB) is one that I recall has been criticized for being much too firmly in the "dynamic" camp.  If you read [Section 1.1 on "features"](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/slib/Feature.html#Feature), you see this right from the beginning:

> SLIB maintains a list of features supported by a Scheme *session*. The set of features provided by a session may change during that session.

The [documentation for the `require` form](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/slib/Require.html#Require) that you use in SLIB to "load" modules continues with this:

> Procedure: **require** *feature*
>
> - If `(provided? feature)` is true, then require just returns.
> - Otherwise, if feature is found in the catalog, then the corresponding files will be loaded and `(provided? feature)` will henceforth return `#t`. That feature is thereafter provided.
> - Otherwise (feature not found in the catalog), an error is signaled.

If you read this carefully, you will be struck that it's framing the whole thing as modules being "loaded" at *runtime*—and not as compile-time linking, which is foreign to the design.

So a "session" is a set of bindings whose *keys*—not just their *values*—changes during the runtime of the program.  Programs are able to *mutate* the session with `provide` and `require`.  They are able to *directly observe* the mutation with `provided?`.  And it is implied that they can indirectly observe the set of identifiers bound in top-level environment change as a result of `require`—a call to `require` causes procedure invocations that would result in a runtime error before its invocation to no longer be so afterwards.

So we can't help but conclude that going by the philosophy of the people who designed this library,  `define` is imperative.  But not every Scheme user or implementer shares this philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

First off Scheme is lexically scoped. Define usually is not limited to top level bindings like it is in Racket. It can create bindings within other procedure bodies.

In some implementations define can manipulate state but only for top level definitions. Otherwise it acts like let and binds a variable to the local scope. To actually take advantage of the top-level rebinding programatically is difficult.

So define doesn't introduce an imperative style into scheme code. Compare define to set! and its relatives, which by modify the variable in whatever environment it is bound, thereby allowing imperative style in scheme code.

Comment: FWIW It's ok to use `define` in a non-top-level scope in Racket. In the REPL you can also use define to declare new variables.